# extract lines from a file that do not fulfill certain criteria

Tags: json, bash, awk, sed, jq

in the following file, i need to get all lines that do not have in them  the following pattern:

```
\"\d\d\d\":[
```

i do not want the line  `"memo": {` or `"notice": "delivered on 17"`, i just want the lines that have `\"\d\d\d\":[`, but instead they have `\"\d\d\":[`, or `\"\s\d\d\":[` etc. How could this be done with sed or awk, or even better with jq?

i just need the lines that do not have in them the `\"\d\d\d\":[` pattern, for example `\"42 \":[` should be reported. Each message line, must have `\"\d\d\d\":[` and not any other variation. For example `\"42a\":[` is also wrong, and should be reported

```
{
  "memo": {
    "notice": "delivered on 17"
  },
  "message": "{\"id\":\"1\",\"401\":[[\" 0\",[\"a\",\"UK\"],[\"b\",\"Euy/ O\"],[\"c\",\"20160811\"],[\"g\",\"R2\"]],[\" 1\",[\"a\",\"UK\"],[\"b\",\"LO\"],[\"c\",\"20160811\"]]]}"
}
{
  "memo": {
    "notice": "delivered on 190"
  },
  "message": "{\"id\":\"2\",\"424\":[[\" 0\",[\"v\",\"UK\"],[\"9\",\"Euy/ O\"],[\"c\",\"20160811\"],[\"g\",\"R2\"]],[\" 1\",[\"a\",\"UK\"],[\"b\",\"LO\"],[\"c\",\"20160811\"]]]}"
}
{
  "memo": {
    "notice": "delivered on 734"
  },
  "message": "{\"id\":\"3\",\"432\":[[\" 0\",[\"a\",\"UK\"],[\"9\",\"Euy/ O\"],[\"c\",\"20160811\"],[\"v\",\"R2\"]],[\" 1\",[\"a\",\"UK\"],[\"b\",\"LO\"],[\"c\",\"20160811\"]]]}"
}
{
  "memo": {
    "notice": "delivered on 1092"
  },
  "message": "{\"id\":\"888\",\"5 2\":[[\" 0\",[\"v\",\"UK\"],[\"b\",\"Euy/ O\"],[\"c\",\"20160811\"],[\"g\",\"R2\"]],[\" 1\",[\"a\",\"UK\"],[\"b\",\"LO\"],[\"c\",\"20160811\"]]]}"
}
```

as an output, I need the id value of the lines that have these problems.

expected output of the above: `id: 888` since in this line there is the erroneous `\"5 2\":[`

Comment: If that's supposed to be JSON, use a tool like `jq` that understands the format.

Comment: @oguzismail i do not want all lines, i just need the lines that do not have in them the \"\d\d\d\":[ pattern, for example \"42 \":[ should be reported. Each message line, must have \"\d\d\d\":[ and not any other variation. For example \"42a\":[ is also wrong

Comment: can you please share expected output

Comment: @oguzismail please provide an answer, so that i could accept it. I like the jq approach. My only problem is that i need the opposite. The lines, that do have an erroneous version of the  "\"[0-9]{3}\"")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Decode all `message`s, select those which do not contain any key matching `\d{3}`, and extract their `id`s.

```
jq '.message | fromjson | select(any(keys_unsorted[]; test("[0-9]{3}")) | not) .id' file
```

Answer (score 0):

> in the following file, i need to get all lines that do not have in
>   them the following pattern:
>
> `\"\d\d\d\":[`

What about

```
awk '$0 ~ /\\"\\d\\d\\d\\":\[/ {next;}{print;}' test.txt | awk '$0 ~ /memo/ {next;}{print;}' | awk '$0 ~ /notice/ {next;}{print;}'
```

> {
>         },
>         "message": "{\"id\":\"1\",\"401\":[[\" 0\",[\"a\",\"UK\"],[\"b\",\"Euy/
>   O\"],[\"c\",\"20160811\"],[\"g\",\"R2\"]],[\"
>   1\",[\"a\",\"UK\"],[\"b\",\"LO\"],[\"c\",\"20160811\"]]]}"
>       }
>       {
>         },
>         "message": "{\"id\":\"2\",\"424\":[[\" 0\",[\"v\",\"UK\"],[\"9\",\"Euy/
>   O\"],[\"c\",\"20160811\"],[\"g\",\"R2\"]],[\"
>   1\",[\"a\",\"UK\"],[\"b\",\"LO\"],[\"c\",\"20160811\"]]]}"
>       }
>       {
>         },
>         "message": "{\"id\":\"3\",\"432\":[[\" 0\",[\"a\",\"UK\"],[\"9\",\"Euy/
>   O\"],[\"c\",\"20160811\"],[\"v\",\"R2\"]],[\"
>   1\",[\"a\",\"UK\"],[\"b\",\"LO\"],[\"c\",\"20160811\"]]]}"
>       }
>       {
>         },
>         "message": "{\"id\":\"888\",\"532\":[[\" 0\",[\"v\",\"UK\"],[\"b\",\"Euy/
>   O\"],[\"c\",\"20160811\"],[\"g\",\"R2\"]],[\"
>   1\",[\"a\",\"UK\"],[\"b\",\"LO\"],[\"c\",\"20160811\"]]]}"
>       }

maybe you still need to clean up some brackets.